# Custom Web Fonts in Emails

Tags: c#, .net, email, fonts, email-attachments

I'm trying to send emails with custom web fonts as attachments. I'm using .NET MimeKit library for email sending. I'm attaching font file as a *Stream* to the *BodyBuilder.LinkedResources* as so:

```
body.LinkedResources.Add($"font{fontUrlIndex}", font.Stream);
```

Next I'm referencing that attachment in the *@font-face* CSS rule in the *url()* so it looks something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomMailingFont';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("cid:font0") format('woff2');
}
```

Problem is that the font file is attached to the email message but the *@font-face* rule doesn't work.

When inspecting that message in the outlook web client the rule looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css" id="x_custom-font-face">
<!--
@font-face
    {font-family:'CustomMailingFont';
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal}
-->
</style>
```

As you can see the *src* property is missing. This mechanism of attaching files works on images in the message. When downloading the message in the *.eml* format and opening it in text editor that *@font-face* rule looks like I have shown before.

What am I missing? Is it even possible to attach custom fonts as files in a email message? Is there a way to see an error message why the *src* property is cropped?

Comment: Custom fonts in an email is not a good idea IMO.  What if the client has 'don't download attachments' ticked?  What if the client is trying to view on a mobile with low data usage.  What if the client viewer is text only (no HTML at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom web fonts require a `@font-face` declaration. And this typically does not work in all email clients. You can see which email clients support it on [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/). As of january 2023, Outlook.com does not support `@font-face` and will remove the `src` property of the declaration.

[image: Can I email… @font-face]